# Reading and Writing (Serializing) static nested class object in different classes

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I want to serialize a Map<String, CustomClass> object which contains a static nested CustomClass object as its value.

```
public class A{

    static Map<String, CustomClass> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map.put("ABC", new CustomClass(1, 2L, "Hello"));
        writeToFile();
    }
    
    private static void writeToFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.ser"));
        out.writeObject(map);
    }

    private static class CustomClass implements Serializable {
        int x;
        long y;
        String z;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 87923834787L;
        private CustomClass (int x, long y, String z) {
         .....
        }
    }

}


public class B {

    static Map<String, CustomClass> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        readFromFile();
    }

    private static void readFromFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.ser"));
        map = out.readObject(); // ClassNotFoundException occured
    }

    private static class CustomClass implements Serializable {
        int x;
        long y;
        String z;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 87923834787L;
        private CustomClass (int x, long y, String z) {
         .....
        }
        
        //some utility methods
        ....
    }

}
```

When I am trying to read the serialized Map object, it throws the ClassNotFoundException. Is it because the same nested class defined under a different class will have a different name or version?

What could be the possible solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because the same inner class defined under different class will have different name or version?

It is because 'same inner class defined under different class' is a contradiction in terms. It *isn't* the same. It is a different class.

NB [`static inner` is *also* a contradiction in terms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

Nested class full name includes enclosing class name. A writes to A$CustomClass and B has B$CustomClass

Answer (score 0):

In your `class B` I have replaced with the below line and it worked fine for me.

```
 map = (Map<String, CustomClass>) out.readObject();//Line no 19
```

Also, I couldn't able to find a method with `readObject(Object)` with Object as a parameter in `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: "readObject(Object)" sorry that was a mistake in typing the demo code here. Please read it as out.readObject()

Comment: Then it means the `Class A` itself not found while running `Class B`. Can u check the classpath before running `Class B`or by logging the classpath while running the program itself by making use of SystemClassloader.